# Reformatting unzipped directories that contain spaces in the names

Tags: directory, rename, subdirectory

I have unzipped directories from the Joint Genome Institute and found that their folder names contain many spaces. I think these spaces are causing many problems when I try to access .gz files within these folders.

```
[Linux@vaughan LIL181_2]$ tree
.
├── Alignment
│   └── QC\ and\ Genome\ Assembly
│       └── JGI\ assembly\ of:\ Metagenome\ Standard\ Draft\ -\ LIL18-4,\ ASSEMBLY_DATE=20230713
│           └── pairedMapped.sam.gz
└── Sequence
    └── Filtered\ Raw\ Data
        └── 52866.2.474993.ACGCTGTA-TTGACGCA.filter-METAGENOME.fastq.gz

5 directories, 2 files
```

I want to unzip the sam file, but I am receiving this error.

```
[Linux@vaughan JGI assembly of: Metagenome Standard Draft - LIL18-4, ASSEMBLY_DATE=20230713]$ unzip pairedMapped.sam.gz 
Archive:  pairedMapped.sam.gz
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of pairedMapped.sam.gz or
        pairedMapped.sam.gz.zip, and cannot find pairedMapped.sam.gz.ZIP, period.
```

I tried to rename the folder QC\ and\ Genome\ Assembly to qc for ease of processing but rename returns the error not enough arguments. I then tried removing the spaces in the actual command, but same error.

```
[Linux@vaughan LIL181_2]$ rename -v QC\ and\ Genome\ Assembly qc
rename: not enough arguments
```

I know it's been a long day but I'm losing my mind! Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the output of `rename --version` ?

Comment: The simple way: `mv 'QC and Genome Assembly' 'qc'`